# Is there a minimum repeating length of noise that we stop perceiving as repetitive?

Tags: noise, psychoacoustics

When I hear white/pink noise looped I can tell that it's being looped, and pick out parts of it even if it's repeating every few seconds.  I was wondering if there's a length of noise that we won't notice is being looped.

Technically any periodic/repetitive signal is actually made up of tones, and very short loops of noise are far more tone-like than noise-like.  The longer the repetitive loop, the closer together the tones become, and if they are all so close together they are within the critical bands of our hearing then we can't perceive them anymore?  But I think I could still hear the random variations in frequency content and notice when it repeats?

Comment: Assuming the listener is not expecting to hear a loop and then identifies it, I'm guessing this time frame would be short and not properly disguised/masked by other elements. Pop music is made up of countless loops but not many people actually pick this up. I don't know how long it is, but I reckon this loop would need a minimal length of being slightly shorter than the average limit of the human attention span.

Answer (score -2):

Its all about editing and crossfading. If you donit well, you won't hear it. If you edit uncorrect you hear even a loop point every hour ;)

Answer (score -2):

Just start the engine of a car. At first you hear every cylinder exploding. Now - put the pedal to the metal! (Keep the clutch down) as the revving starts the song from the v8. Now when does the drums start to become a song?